# When does compaction in kafka happens if min.cleanable.dirty.ratio, max.compaction.lag.ms and max.compaction.lag.ms parameters are set?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've set for my topic these three parameters:

```
max.compaction.lag.ms: 43200000

min.compaction.lag.ms

min.cleanable.dirty.ratio: "0.5
```

Did I get it right that compaction on this topic will happen AFTER the time specified  for "max.compaction.lag.ms" will elapse EVEN if the value specified for min.cleanable.dirty.ratio has not been met?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be right. So, as you have set it up, compaction starts if it has been at least 12 hours since the last one, regardless of the cleanable dirty ratio condition.